# SQL Server Stored Procedure Bacup Database into Network Share

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-backups

I have followed "[How to schedule and automate backups of SQL Server databases in SQL Server Express](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2019698/how-to-schedule-and-automate-backups-of-sql-server-databases-in-sql-se)" article to create backup a SQL Server Express database. Basically this creates a stored procedure and it is called by a .BAT file periodically by Task Scheduler. If destination is set to a local folder for example D:\Data it works fine, however I need to create backups on the folder \\Server\Folder I get access denied error.

User domain\myuser is always logged in. This user has write permission into folder \\Server\Folder. I tried adding user as Login and then tried to call stored procedure `EXECUTE AS domain\myuser` but it did not help.

I cannot create a network map because of limitations. Is there a workaround for backup into a network folder?

When I run SSMS and call the SP I get the following error. I logged in as domain\myuser user and opened SSMS. If I browse folder \\Server\Folder in Windows Explorer I can create files, so user domain\myuser has write permissions on the folder.

[image: SSMS Error]

Comment: @TomTom of course I tried it. If you are administrator it works. It is not because of spelling mistake. I am also domain administrator and when I test it worked locally, but on production envitonment it did not work. The error as I said: Accedd denied.

Answer (score 0):

I navigated to your link you shared and read the following:

> 7. In the Enter the user name field, type a user name, and then type a password in the Enter the password field.
>
> Note This user should at least be assigned the BackupOperator role at
>   SQL Server level if you are using one of the batch files in example 1,
>   3, or 4.

Are you specifying the domain administrator credentials here? i.e. The credentials for the network share?

Comment: This is for the Windows Task Scheduler, I tried, same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the account that the SQL Server service is using has the appropriera permissions on the share.

Comment: I logged in as domain\myuser user and opened SSMS. If I browse folder \\Server\Folder in Windows Explorer I can create files, so user domain\myuser has write permissions on the folder.

Comment: _The SQL Server service account_ needs access. Your account access is irrelevent

Comment: Nee Nick's comment above and also my reply. It is *the service account* for SQL server that need permissions.